# Should the Book of Enoch be included in modern Bibles?

Tags: satan, leviticus, apocrypha, enoch

Given that Enoch is well respected by the authors of the Bible, do you believe that the Book should be included in modern Bibles? I believe it should because it is scripture based and backs up and makes sense of text in the Old Testament and New Testament. If you believe that Enoch should not be included and was right to be left out of the Bible, please state the objects with supporting evidence, please. Thank you.

As an example, I post information on Azazel who is Lucifer and is mentioned in Enoch and Leviticus.

Source: [Was Azazel Lucifer (Quora)](https://www.quora.com/Was-Azazel-Lucifer)

Azazel wasn’t Lucifer… he IS Lucifer.

“And the whole earth has been corrupted through the works that were taught by Azâzêl: to him ascribe all sin.”

Book of Enoch, Chapter 10 Verse 9

If you do a degree of research into this subject, you will come to learn some startling things. Example, in the original oral tradition of the Quran, Iblis, the Arabic name for Lucifer, was originally known as Azazel.

The name means “The Left Hand of God” as he is the counter-part of the “Right Hand of God” (Yeshuah aka Jesus Christ). In some translations of the Book of Leviticus, it speaks of Aaron sacrificing two goats. One is to Jehovah and the other is to Azazel. The modern translations change Azazel to “scapegoat”. The Templar Knights secretly worshiped a goat-headed demon known as Baphomet - this is yet another name for Azazel. He is known by many names such as, Samyaza, Samael, Asrael, Moloch, Satan, Lucifer, etc.

Now for the Old Testament. Specifically, Leviticus 16 using the Complete Jewish Bible translation.

Leviticus 16 Complete Jewish Bible

Parashah 29: Acharei Mot (After the death) 16:1–18:30

[In regular years read with Parashah 30, in leap years read separately]

16 Adonai spoke with Moshe after the death of Aharon’s two sons, when they tried to sacrifice before Adonai and died; 2 Adonai said to Moshe, “Tell your brother Aharon not to come at just any time into the Holy Place beyond the curtain, in front of the ark-cover which is on the ark, so that he will not die; because I appear in the cloud over the ark-cover.

3 “Here is how Aharon is to enter the Holy Place: with a young bull as a sin offering and a ram as a burnt offering. 4 He is to put on the holy linen tunic, have the linen shorts next to his bare flesh, have the linen sash wrapped around him, and be wearing the linen turban — they are the holy garments. He is to bathe his body in water and put them on.

5 “He is to take from the community of the people of Isra’el two male goats for a sin offering and one ram for a burnt offering. 6 Aharon is to present the bull for the sin offering which is for himself and make atonement for himself and his household. 7 He is to take the two goats and place them before Adonai at the entrance to the tent of meeting. 8 Then Aharon is to cast lots for the two goats, one lot for Adonai and the other for ‘Az’azel. 9 Aharon is to present the goat whose lot fell to Adonai and offer it as a sin offering. 10 But the goat whose lot fell to ‘Az’azel is to be presented alive to Adonai to be used for making atonement over it by sending it away into the desert for ‘Az’azel.

11 “Aharon is to present the bull of the sin offering for himself; he will make atonement for himself and his household; he is to slaughter the bull of the sin offering which is for himself. 12 He is to take a censer full of burning coals from the altar before Adonai and, with his hands full of ground, fragrant incense, bring it inside the curtain. 13 He is to put the incense on the fire before Adonai, so that the cloud from the incense will cover the ark-cover which is over the testimony, in order that he not die. 14 He is to take some of the bull’s blood and sprinkle it with his finger on the ark-cover toward the east; and in front of the ark-cover he is to sprinkle some of the blood with his finger seven times.

15 “Next, he is to slaughter the goat of the sin offering which is for the people, bring its blood inside the curtain and do with its blood as he did with the bull’s blood, sprinkling it on the ark-cover and in front of the ark-cover. 16 He will make atonement for the Holy Place because of the uncleannesses of the people of Isra’el and because of their transgressions — all their sins; and he is to do the same for the tent of meeting which is there with them right in the middle of their uncleannesses. 17 No one is to be present in the tent of meeting from the time he enters the Holy Place to make atonement until the time he comes out, having made atonement for himself, for his household and for the entire community of Isra’el. (LY: ii) 18 Then he is to go out to the altar that is before Adonai and make atonement for it; he is to take some of the bull’s blood and some of the goat’s blood and put it on all the horns of the altar. 19 He is to sprinkle some of the blood on it with his finger seven times, thus purifying it and setting it apart from the uncleannesses of the people of Isra’el.

20 “When he has finished atoning for the Holy Place, the tent of meeting and the altar, he is to present the live goat. 21 Aharon is to lay both his hands on the head of the live goat and confess over it all the transgressions, crimes and sins of the people of Isra’el; he is to put them on the head of the goat and then send it away into the desert with a man appointed for the purpose. 22 The goat will bear all their transgressions away to some isolated place, and he is to let the goat go in the desert.

23 “Aharon is to go back into the tent of meeting, where he is to remove the linen garments he put on when he entered the Holy Place, and he is to leave them there. 24 Then he is to bathe his body in water in a holy place, put on his other clothes, come out and offer his burnt offering and the burnt offering of the people, thus making atonement for himself and for the people. (RY: ii, LY: iii) 25 He is to make the fat of the sin offering go up in smoke on the altar.

26 “The man who let go the goat for ‘Az’azel is to wash his clothes and bathe his body in water; afterwards, he may return to the camp.

27 “The bull for the sin offering and the goat for the sin offering, whose blood was brought in to make atonement in the Holy Place, is to be carried outside the camp; there they are to burn up completely their hides, meat and dung. 28 The person burning them is to wash his clothes and bathe his body in water; afterwards, he may return to the camp.

29 “It is to be a permanent regulation for you that on the tenth day of the seventh month you are to deny yourselves and not do any kind of work, both the citizen and the foreigner living with you. 30 For on this day, atonement will be made for you to purify you; you will be clean before Adonai from all your sins. 31 It is a Shabbat of complete rest for you, and you are to deny yourselves.

“This is a permanent regulation. 32 The cohen anointed and consecrated to be cohen in his father’s place will make the atonement; he will put on the linen garments, the holy garments; 33 he will make atonement for the Especially Holy Place; he will make atonement for the tent of meeting and the altar; and he will make atonement for the cohanim and for all the people of the community. 34 This is a permanent regulation for you, to make atonement for the people of Isra’el because of all their sins once a year.” Moshe did as Adonai had ordered him.

Source: https://www.christianity.com/wiki/angels-and-demons/who-was-azazel.html

What Do We Know about Azazel from the Apocrypha?

In the Apocrypha, Azazel is a leader of rebellious angels, as seen in the Book of Enoch. He leads the pre-Flood civilizations of men, giants (perhaps Nephilim), in all matters of warfare and witchcraft.

Once beautiful, and now a fallen serpent or carrion bird, Azazel, according to Hebraic literature, tried to corrupt humanity. Most Jewish literature describes him as having a red appearance, like a demon, with yellow eyes and wearing goat skulls.

It also appears that, according to Jewish mythology, Azazel led the charge in having sexual relations with mortal women and having half-divine, half-human children known as the Nephilim.

What’s interesting about Azazel is that he has corrupted humanity so much that Jewish literature encourages readers and listeners to ascribe all sin onto him. In other words, scapegoat him. Place your sins on him, as you did with the goat before driving it out into the desert.

So, the next question is "What does the Bible say about the Nephilim?

Genesis 6:1-6 Complete Jewish Bible

6 In time, when men began to multiply on earth, and daughters were born to them, 2 the sons of God saw that the daughters of men were attractive; and they took wives for themselves, whomever they chose. 3 Adonai said, “My Spirit will not live in human beings forever, for they too are flesh; therefore their life span is to be 120 years.” 4 The N’filim were on the earth in those days, and also afterwards, when the sons of God came in to the daughters of men, and they bore children to them; these were the ancient heroes, men of renown.

(Maftir) 5 Adonai saw that the people on earth were very wicked, that all the imaginings of their hearts were always of evil only. 6 Adonai regretted that he had made humankind on the earth; it grieved his heart.

And, also:

Numbers 13:33 Complete Jewish Bible

33 We saw the N’filim, the descendants of ‘Anak, who was from the N’filim; to ourselves we looked like grasshoppers by comparison, and we looked that way to them too!”

Thus, we can see that The Book of Enoch should have been included in the Bible, as it contains missing information that backs up Bible scripture and helps us to have more understanding of those scriptures, and the origins of our advances and also our sins.

Comment: Your main question, and the subsidiary ones, appear to have been answered already on this site. I direct you to the link below, and from there you can see many related questions.  https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/8576/why-is-the-book-of-enoch-not-regarded-as-canonical  ~Further, giving quotes which you think supports your view that it should be, require to go in an answer box.

Answer (score 1):

**Should the *Book of Enoch* be included in modern Bibles?**

The short answer is **no**

There is is just one exception to this rule and that is with the Ethiopian Orthodox Church.

The ***Book of Enoch*** is simply not recognized as being part of the depot of the faith. In other words, is it is not recognized as a canonical inspired book in any denomination except the Ethiopian Orthodox Church.

> Various Aramaic fragments found in the Dead Sea Scrolls, as well as Koine Greek and Latin fragments, are proof that the Book of Enoch was known by Jews and early Near Eastern Christians. This book was also quoted by some 1st and 2nd century authors as in the Testaments of the Twelve Patriarchs. Authors of the New Testament were also familiar with some content of the story. A short section of 1 Enoch (1:9) is cited in the New Testament Epistle of Jude, Jude 1:14–15, and is attributed there to "Enoch the Seventh from Adam" (1 Enoch 60:8), although this section of 1 Enoch is a midrash on Deuteronomy 33:2. Several copies of the earlier sections of 1 Enoch were preserved among the Dead Sea Scrolls.
>
> It is not part of the biblical canon used by Jews, apart from Beta Israel (Ethiopian Jews). **While the Ethiopian Orthodox Tewahedo Church and Eritrean Orthodox Tewahedo Church consider the Book of Enoch as canonical, other Christian groups regard it as non-canonical or non-inspired, but may accept it as having some historical or theological interest.**
>
> It is today wholly extant only in the Ethiopian Ge'ez language, with earlier Aramaic fragments from the Dead Sea Scrolls and a few Greek and Latin fragments. For this and other reasons, the traditional Ethiopian belief is that the original language of the work was Ge'ez, whereas modern scholars argue that it was first written in either Aramaic or Hebrew, the languages first used for Jewish texts; Ephraim Isaac suggests that the Book of Enoch, like the Book of Daniel, was composed partially in Aramaic and partially in Hebrew: No Hebrew version is known to have survived. The book itself asserts that its author was Enoch, before the biblical flood.
>
> The most complete Book of Enoch comes from Ethiopic manuscripts, maṣḥafa hēnok (መጽሐፈ ሄኖክ), written in Ge'ez, which were brought to Europe by James Bruce in the late 18th century and were translated into English in the 19th century. - [Book of Enoch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Enoch)

Although it is not recognized as a an inspired work from God and thus non-canonical, it may still have some historical interest for some Christians here and there.

For example, the Catholic Church does not recognize the *Book of Enoch* as being a canonically inspired book. But many years back, there was a movement to publish this book as well as a few other smaller non-canonical (apocryphal) books as an appendage at the end of their bibles for as an historical reference work that some would like to see preserved: **Least they perish altogether** (***ne pereant***). This movement did not last long and one would be hard pressed to find such editions now.

Theses editions made it clear that those books found at the end of the Bible were non-canonical works were printed with these editions as works to be used for reference sources only since not everything quoted from the Bible is done so from within the Scriptures themselves, but may have come from apocryphal sources!

Comment: Thank you. An excellent answer. I do like the book, and it does provide a good historical record of our beginnings. It will continue to be part of my extra-Biblical studies.